# Canvas Pattern not repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, canvas

I am making a Canvas Pattern using the following javascript:

```
//$('#canvas1').height($(document).height());
//console.log($('#canvas1').width($(document).width()));

var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

// set up a pattern
var pattern = document.createElement('canvas');
pattern.width = 80;
pattern.height = 80;
var pctx = pattern.getContext('2d');

pctx.beginPath();
pctx.lineWidth = "3";
pctx.strokeStyle = "red";
pctx.rect(74, 74, 3, 3);  
pctx.stroke();

var pattern = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
ctx.rect(0,0,800,800);
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fill();
```

The resulting pattern doesn't seem to repeat even when the `ctx.rect` values are defined as 800. The canvas is as follows:

```
<canvas id="canvas1"style="position:absolute;left:0;top:0;"></canvas>
```

How can I make it repeat throughout the height and width of current page. I know that I can set the height and width using `jQuery` and I tested that, but the pattern is still not repeating. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess you got confused with [.rect()](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp)'s parameters. It should be `pctx.rect(3, 3, 74, 74)`.

```js
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

// set up a pattern
var pattern = document.createElement('canvas');
pattern.width = 80;
pattern.height = 80;
var pctx = pattern.getContext('2d');

pctx.beginPath();
pctx.lineWidth = "3";
pctx.strokeStyle = "red";
pctx.rect(3, 3, 74, 74);
pctx.stroke();

var _pattern = ctx.createPattern(pattern, "repeat");
ctx.rect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
ctx.fillStyle = _pattern;
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas1" width="320" height="320" style="border: 1px solid black; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;"></canvas>
```

Comment: I do actually want small red squares on the bottom right of the one rectangle and make it repeat throughout the page as background. So it will look like small red squares throughout the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's the root of your problem, but when you change the width, you should write `pattern.style.width = "80px";`
The same applies for height
Let me know if that fixes your problems

Comment: @Arihant I ran your code and I think it works. It displays three red squares equally distant from each other, centered vertically in the canvas. Isn't that what you want

Comment: well, actually no. I want then to repeat throughout the height and width of the screen, like a background

Comment: Do you try `ctx.rect(0,0,can.width,can.height);` ?

Comment: @defghi1977 That's what I was going to suggest, but I don't think the can.width and can.height is necessary